# glmnet error when running a documentation example

Tags: r, glmnet

I am currently running an example in the `glmnet` documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf page 3):

```
> x=matrix(rnorm(100*20),100,20)
> y=rnorm(100)
> fit1=glmnet(x,y)
> plot(fit1,xvar="lambda")
```

However, I get this error message

> Error in as.vector((beta %*% ones) > 0) : 
>         no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

and I need help to understand why the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I run exactly the code you put and it works.
Maybe you should remove your workspace and run again the code.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have removed my workspace, re-installed R, but without success.

Comment: I think the problem should appear after runing the third line. Isn't it? Could you write the result of running `class(x)`and `class(y)` after running the two first lines?

Comment: The problem is solved! My version of R (2.13) does not like `glmnet`. Thanks